# How can I get rid of this ModuleNotFoundError?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm, conda

I was working with TensorFlow when an error was thrown.

Here's some sample code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(tf.__version__)
```

The stacktrace:

```
Python 3.7.9 (default, Aug 31 2020, 17:10:11) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32  
runfile('C:/Users/ASUS P550L/PycharmProjects/nn_tensorflow/main.py', wdir='C:/Users/ASUSP550L/PycharmProjects/nn_tensorflow')  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>  
  File "D:\Programs\PyCharm 2020.2.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197,   in runfile  
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script  
  File "D:\Programs\PyCharm 2020.2.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line  
18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)  
  File "C:/Users/ASUS P550L/PycharmProjects/nn_tensorflow/main.py", line 1, in <module>  
    import tensorflow as tf  
  File "D:\Programs\PyCharm 2020.2.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py",   line 21, in do_import  
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)  
  File "C:\Users\ASUS P550L\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>  
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util  
  File "D:\Programs\PyCharm 2020.2.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import  
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)  
  File "C:\Users\ASUS P550L\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "D:\Programs\PyCharm 2020.2.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)`  
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.eager'
```

I'm running TensorFlow v2.1.0 in a Conda3 and Python v3.7 environment set with the PyCharm integrated plugin. I tried with `pip` instead of conda but the error still remains, with the 2020.1.3 version of PyCharm (with Anaconda plugin) and with 3.6 version of python but nothing seems to happen. Similar questions on StackOverflow have mentioned that this was a problem with earlier versions of TensorFlow (<1.5) that didn't support eager but I'm running a much newer version and I don't think this can be useful.

Comment: _I'm running TensorFlow v2.1.0 in a Conda3 and Python v3.7 environment_ The traceback makes it seems like that isn't the case, can you confirm that?

Comment: Thanks a lot for improving my question! However, where do you see that this isn't the case?

Comment: I've checked. Pycharm python version is v3.7.9, my system python version is v3.7.6 and conda is v4.8.5. Now i have to make it all the same version of python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue might happen if PyCharm uses a different python or python in a different environment. Check in PyCharm terminal and in you computer command line using the following command. The results should match, if they don't then set the PyCharm one to the right path.